# How can I package symbolic link in node_modules with `serverless?

Tags: aws-lambda, yarnpkg, serverless-framework, yarn-workspaces

I am using `serverless` to package nodejs application. I am using `yarn workspace` in my project.

```
- common
- projectA
- projectB
```

the `projectA` and `projectB` are using `common` module which is managed by `yarn workspace`. It creates a link inside `node_modules/common -> ../common`. But when I package the application with `sls deploy`, it doesn't inlude the link `node_modules/common`. How can I make it package symbolic link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You should start using code bundler.

### What is code bundler?

What code bundler does:

1. It scans your AWS Lambda code structure through all of the files, starting from handler file.
2. It goes through all of the imports to create a tree of dependencies.
3. Then it inlines all of those dependencies into single "fat" file.
4. After that you are free to deploy your application, which has only single file.

As you can see, it's a perfect match for AWS Lambda and your use case.

All of the dependencies from `common` package will be included in the output file.

Also code bundlers have other cool features, like removing all of the unneeded files, that are defined in libraries that you use, but you are not using them directly. Due to this output package size of your Lambda will be a lot smaller, [which will decrease cold starts.](https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/)

### How to achieve that using Serveless Framework

The easiest way is to start with [serverless-webpack](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) plugin, which includes Webpack (one of the most popular code bundlers) and some most common configurations for it.

After adding this plugin, simply configure it in `serverless.yml`:

```
custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: 'webpack.config.js'   # you can remove it, it's the same as default
    packager: 'yarn'
```

Now you need to configure Webpack using `webpack.config.js` file. There are a lot of possibilities to configure it and the example below is the most basic one:

```
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  stats: 'minimal',
  devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
  externals: [{'aws-sdk': 'commonjs aws-sdk'}],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
  },
};
```

Now when you call `sls package` in `projectA` or `projectB`, then after unzipping  `./.serverless/functionName.zip`, you will find just single "fat" file, that will include all of the required dependencies.

During `sls deploy` phase, this file will be deployed as Lambda handler.

### Correctly defining dependencies

Make sure, that `common` package is listed as dependency of `projectA` and `projectB`:

```
// common/package.json

{
  "name": "@your-project/common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
}

// projectA/package.json

{
  "name": "@your-project/packageA",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
      "@your-project/common": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks to this, you will be able to reference commons in pakcageA imports via:

```
import exampleHelper from '@your-project/common/src/exampleHelper';
```

---

Project using this approach can be found on my Github here:

https://github.com/PatrykMilewski/serverless-series

Comment: I was at first suspicious of the answer because it had 0 upvotes, and I have tried many solutions before, but serverless-webpack is absolutely the right answer. Serverless was good before serverless-webpack, but now it's absolutely fantastic. Thank you very much

Comment: @AndréPena No problem! Also a few things changed in my personal best practices. Check out serverless-esbuild plugin. The bundling size is the same, but the bundling process is around 100 times faster and also it needs a lot less configuration. If you want you can check out one of my examples here:
https://github.com/PatrykMilewski/serverless-monorepo-template/tree/master/stacks/first